# How to use formControl to disable an individual button?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have to disable this button if no checkbox is selected.

`<button (click) = "onDeleteSelected()" 
        [disabled] = "mflagDisableMoveTo.value"> Delete selected </button>`

In typescript I have:
`mflagDisableMoveTo = new FormControl( { value: 'true' } )`

This form control is not a part of any formGroup.

Where am I supposed to put `[formControl] = "mflagDisableMoveTo"` in the above HTML code?

How to use `formControl` to disable an individual button?

Comment: why do you want to use FormControlDirective in this case? There is no benefit. Moreover, I don't think you can use it with a HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: @htn What is the other way with reactive forms?

Comment: Forget reactive forms or template driven forms. You need neither of them to disable a button, just a basic binding is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, true is not a string, so you need to write true, not 'true'

```
mflagDisableMoveTo = new FormControl({ value: true })
```

You can get any FormControl value by: FormControl.value

Since you have new FormControl({ value: true }), right answer is: mflagDisableMoveTo.value.value

```
<button (click)="onDeleteSelected()" [disabled] = "mflagDisableMoveTo.value.value"> Delete selected </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day:
The formControl has to have a false initial value, what I did is use the value of the formControl in the disabled button:

1.Create my formControl in app.component.ts

`import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";`

```
 check = new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]);
```

2.app.component.html

`<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="check" />
<button (click)="showControl()" [disabled]="check.value === false">Send</button>`